# Selenium - search for items inside parent

Tags: java, html, testing, selenium

I've just started writing some selenium autotests in java for my `HTML5` web application. I was wondering if it was possible rather than adding `id` attributes onto everything to search for a number of items inside a `div` with an `id`.

For example, I have a `div` with `id`: `sfn-PopupMenu`. There are several items with `class="gwt-MenuItem"` and `role="menuitem"`. And I'd like to be able to find and control each of these without giving them individual Ids.

Is this possible? Or should I just put ids on everything.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: While it's possible to fetch the parent WebElement, then programmatically walk the WebElement children, I would not suggest doing this.  It's extremely slow as each time you access a WebElement it validates it (WebElement is a proxy).  As an example, we had a table with 20 rows in it.  I tried to convert the contents into a simple POJO by walking the WebElement tree starting with the top table element, and it took over 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Selenium, you can also search elements by [CSS selectors](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp#starting-to-use-css-instead-of-xpath) or [XPath expressions](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp#useful-xpath-patterns). Without the actual HTML code it is hard to say what is the best here. But in general, you should first try to use ID, then CSS and if not possible XPath.

You could perhaps do something like this:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#sfn-PopupMenu .gwt-MenuItem"));
```